# Create a network of elements in a nested list (python)

Tags: python, graph, nested-lists

I am new to technical/programming world; kindly bear terminological flaws.

Consider a nested list:

`[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f'], ['b', 'e', 'i', 'j', 'k', 't'], ['a', 'i', 'j', 'l'], ['a', 'b', 'm', 'n', 'o'], ['b', 'c', 'e', 'm']]`

I want to:

1. Create a network/map/graph of elements, such that all elements in a sublist are inter-related. From this, create a master network/map/graph of all list.

See the image (for the above nested list):

[Conceptual/Sublist Network Output: Individual Graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8SgK.jpg)

[Desired Network Output: Master Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgsyv.jpg)

2. Create a set of elements occurring where two/three elements occur jointly.

E.g.: In the given list, (`'a'`, `'b'`) and (`'b'`, `'c'`, `'e'`) respectively occur in the sublists **1**, **2**, and **5**, and sublists **2** and **6**. Thus, wherever there is (`'b'`, `'c'`, `'e'`), there (the required set) is {`'a'`, `'f'`, `'m'`}.

3. Find percentage-points of occurrence for two/more elements on graph.

E.g.: In the given list, what percentage of sublists containing `'a'` contain `'c'` and vice-versa. That is, find the same for each element against each element. Here, `'a'` occurs in 4 sublists, and `'c'` is in 2 of them. Thus, *`'c'`, where `'a'`* = **0.5**. Similarly, *`'a'`, where `'c'`* = **0.6**.

---

My problem here is: how to store the first relation and use that to compare ahead and build-on new ones. Here, for first element `'a'`, store {`'b'`, `'c'`, `'d'`} and so on. I haven't been able to move ahead. Any direction/guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your first question you can construct the graph by creating all edges that originate from the subgraphs. The code below will give you a master graph where you can then try to solve the rest of your computer science assignments with.

```py
from itertools import combinations

list_of_sub_graphs = [
    [a, b, c, d],
    [a, b, c, e, f],
    [b, e, i, j, k, t],
    [a, i, j, l],
    [a, b, m, n, o],
    [b, c, e, m]
]

edges = []
for subgraph in list_of_sub_graphs:
    edges_sub_graph = list(combinations(subgraph, 2))
    edges.extend(edges_sub_graph)

set(edges)
```

```
Out[8]: 
{('a', 'b'),
 ('a', 'c'),
 ('a', 'd'),
 ('a', 'e'),
 ('a', 'f'),
 ('a', 'i'),
 ('a', 'j'),
 ('a', 'l'),
 ('a', 'm'),
 ('a', 'n'),
 ('a', 'o'),
 ('b', 'c'),
 ('b', 'd'),
 ('b', 'e'),
 ('b', 'f'),
 ('b', 'i'),
 ('b', 'j'),
 ('b', 'k'),
 ('b', 'm'),
 ('b', 'n'),
 ('b', 'o'),
 ('b', 't'),
 ('c', 'd'),
 ('c', 'e'),
 ('c', 'f'),
 ('c', 'm'),
 ('e', 'f'),
 ('e', 'i'),
 ('e', 'j'),
 ('e', 'k'),
 ('e', 'm'),
 ('e', 't'),
 ('i', 'j'),
 ('i', 'k'),
 ('i', 'l'),
 ('i', 't'),
 ('j', 'k'),
 ('j', 'l'),
 ('j', 't'),
 ('k', 't'),
 ('m', 'n'),
 ('m', 'o'),
 ('n', 'o')}
```

Comment: Oh and for this to run you need to define your nodes, e.g. `a="a"`

Comment: Thanks. I was able to create a Master Graph. The part of your code first helps in creating a dictionary of adjacency list, then goes to the ```add_edges_from``` method of the graph object available in networkx library.

Comment: Yeah networkx is a good libary to work with here